# Как сразу указать координаты центра вращения элемента SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animation

1. Поставить координаты  круга по центру получается только с подбором это transform='rotate(-90 60 60)'
2. Как можно поставить координаты  круга по центру сразу без подбора ?

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >
  <!-- Фон серого цвета -->
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
  <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
  <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' stroke-dashoffset='314' stroke-dasharray='314' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate
  attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='314; 0'
  />
  </circle>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения размеров воспользуйтесь методом JS [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

**MDN web docs**

> **getBBox()** позволяет нам определить координаты самого маленького прямоугольника, в который помещается объект. Возвращаемые координаты
> относятся к текущему пространству svg, то есть после применения всех
> атрибутов геометрии ко всем элементам, содержащимся в целевом
> элементе.

Другими словами, мы можем получить координаты (x,y) верхнего левого угла прямоугольника, который описывает круг, в вашем примере
Ширину и высоту этого прямоугольника - `width`, `height`

Вычисляем координаты центра окружности

```
let bb = circ.getBBox();

console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2)
console.log(bb.y + bb.height / 2)
```

Ниже полный пример

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >
  <!-- Фон серого цвета -->
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
  <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
  <circle id="circ" r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' stroke-dashoffset='314' stroke-dasharray='314' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate
  attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='314; 0'
  />
  </circle>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text>
</svg> 
<script> 
let bb = circ.getBBox();

console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2)
console.log(bb.y + bb.height / 2)
</script>
```

Comment: как получить первое число - 90 ? transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' ?

Comment: @Leks 90 -  это угол поворота всей окружности на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки. Этот параметр устанавливают в зависимости от задачи. В данном примере повернули на четверть круга против часовой стрелки, чтобы анимация начиналась из верхней точки.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Leks Да не за что, задавай вопросы. Всегда рад помочь